# Highlight menu item depending on current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to highlight a menu item depending if it's on the current page. The code below is currently highlighting every menu item because it's within the foreach loop. How can I highlight the taxonomy term if it's on a certain page id and ONLY that term (not every one)?

```
                    <?php $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'blog' );
                        $terms = get_terms('blog', $args);

                        $count = count($terms); $i=0;
                        if ($count > 0) {
                            $cape_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
                            echo $postid;
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                $i++;
                                $absolute = get_bloginfo('url');
                                $postid = get_the_ID();
                                if($postid == "561") {
                                    $term_list .= '<a class="menu-active" style="padding-left:30px;width:88%!IMPORTANT;" href="' . $absolute . '/blog/' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                                } else {
                                    $term_list .= '<a style="padding-left:30px;width:88%!IMPORTANT;" href="' . $absolute . '/blog/' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                                } } ?>

                            <?php echo $term_list; } ?>
```

Comment: Wordpress has a built in navigation function. Why don't you use that? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu it add a class if it is the selected page.

Comment: @CharliePrynn I'd love to use that but any idea how I would work that into my code??? It's listing custom taxonomy terms so it's not a straight forward page listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to query the taxonomy terms belonging to the current page and compare their id-s in the foreach loop.

The `get_the_ID()` function returns the id of the current post, not the current taxonomy.

Here is a link to a wordpress related question which shows how you can query current taxonomy terms:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20431/how-to-get-taxonomy-term-of-the-current-page-and-populate-queries-in-the-templat